# Cant Fix Error NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays Angular9

Tags: angular

I'm new at Angular, I looked at similar questions, but none of them helped me. I am going to receive an object like the following, and I need to create a list with the info:

```
{
"Status": "OK",
"Data": [
    {
        "Id": 1,
        "Solicitante": "Juan Perez",
        "FechaHora": "2020-08-13 20:00",
        "Personas": 10,
        "Fono": " 56 99 222-2222",
        "Email": "miemail@gmail.com",
        "Mensaje": "Quiero una cotizacion urgente",
        "Estado": "Ingresado",
        "Canal": "Pagina Web"
    },
    {
        "Id": 2,
        "Solicitante": "Rodrigo Trigo",
        "FechaHora": "2020-08-13 21:00",
        "Personas": 3,
        "Fono": " 56 99 222-3333",
        "Email": "mi@gmail.com",
        "Mensaje": "Quiero otra cotizacion urgente",
        "Estado": "Ingresado",
        "Canal": "Facebook"
    },
    {
        "Id": 3,
        "Solicitante": "Luis Silva",
        "FechaHora": "2021-01-13 08:00",
        "Personas": 3,
        "Fono": " 56 99 444-3333",
        "Email": "lsilva@gmail.com",
        "Mensaje": "Quiero cotizacion urgente",
        "Estado": "Ingresado",
        "Canal": "Whatsapp"
    },
    
]
```

and here is my http service to receive it:

```
     getPosts()
  {
    return this.http.get(this.url)
  }
```

And I called the service like this:

```
data:any;
  constructor(private postData:PostsService){}
  ngOnInit()
  {
    this.postData.getPosts().subscribe((result)=>{
      console.warn("result", result)
      this.data=result
    })
  }
```

But when the page load, it returns :

```
ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
```

I can't fix the error, I've tried but it's beyond me. Please help

Comment: You should post the Html where you use the ngFor.

Comment: Could you please share your this.data result JSON?. If the result json is not an array then you will face this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you didn't show your ngFor code in your html. But it's clear you are trying to loop through an object that is not an array. My guess is you want to do something like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of data.Data">
```